# Cannot find symbols compilation error

Tags: java

I think I formatted something wrong or there is a logic error, in all honesty I don't know.  I commented in at the bottom of the program the errors.  All help is extremely appreciated.

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    String userInput;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string of characters: ");
    userInput = kb.nextLine();
    int length = userInput.length();

    for (count=0; length<count; count++) {
          char letter=userInput.charAt(count);
          System.out.print(letter + " ");
        }
  }
```

Errors:

```
javac "StringDown.java" (in directory: /home/user/Downloads)
StringDown.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable count
location: class StringDown
    for (count=0; length<count; count++)
         ^
StringDown.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable count
location: class StringDown
    for (count=0; length<count; count++)
                         ^
StringDown.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable count
location: class StringDown
    for (count=0; length<count; count++)
                                ^
StringDown.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable count
location: class StringDown
         System.out.print(userInput.charAt(count));
                                           ^
4 errors
Compilation failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (count=0; length<count; count++)
```

In addition to the other answers recommending `int count=0;`, I'm thinking you've probably got a logic problem.  Assuming you fix what others have pointed out, and do this:

```
for(int count=0; length<count; count++)
```

You're only modifying the size of `count`.  You're never modifying the size of `length`.  And your check is `length<count`, and you're modifying `count` with `++`.  Which means one of two things will happen.

1. When `length >= 0`, you'll never enter the body of the `for` loop.
2. When `length < 0`, you'll enter an infinite loop where `length<count` will always return `true`.

(And given that you're setting `length` by checking the length of a `String`, you'll always get the first scenario in this specific example.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the logic error, although as written, length cannot be < 0.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace is telling you where the error exists. Variables need to be declared with a type keyword before they can be used. Add the `int` keyword so that the variable `count` can be used within the loop

```
for (int count = 0; length < count; count++) {
     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop

```
for (count = 0; length < count; count++) {
```

That should be

```
for (int count = 0; length < count; count++) {
```

Telling that count is an `int` type.

**As a side note:** shift to an IDE ASAP. So that you can more concentrate on your logic, Rather than end up with these type of compilation errors

Comment: @xmoex Best thing is it's free :)

Comment: So are Netbeans and IntelliJ Community Edition; it doesn't matter which IDE. Whether or not an IDE is a good idea for a beginner is a different discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of count as int is missing, below is correct code.

```
 for (int count=0; length<count; count++)
```

Comment: Correct, but a bit behind.